cd /test/ ; tar -czvf test-file /test/abc, result: gzip: short write tar: write error: Broken pipe
I develop a application software, it can tar debug log file and upload to cloud, but the function unwork currently, tar function probable show fail "gzip: short write tar: write error: Broken pipe".
cmd of application always same ex:
sprintf(cmd,"cd /home/root/;tar -czvf %s-DClog-%d-Now.7z /home/root/dclogs", ModTcpIPA->DC1SN[0], nowtime);
system(cmd);.
I check change code currently, it add https protocol to upload other data. I don't know the relation.
anthoer information, I find when tar is not work on application, I can successfully run the same command directly under Linux.
I suspect that the continued use of a certain function in the application is causing the issue.
Could anybody give me some suggest?
Thank you!

When you’re running commands manually your shell has a PATH variable set where it searches for binaries. In your code you probably don’t have that path set. Then you need to specify commands with their absolute path I.e. /usr/bin/tar rather than tar or set up that path

i will try it, but the issue is random, sometime i reboot the system, it work normally, if root cause is path, it shall be everytime failed, right?

@NiuAr - did you mention this behaviour in the question?

@NiuAr Check the disk space and you have free space means, you can try to tar some other folder and try.

@bravo "tar function probable show fail", I tell not clear, sorry.

@Vinoth Chitrarasu i have checked my space, it is ok. I can use same cmd and it is sccueess, so i think is not space issue.

@HBruijn I try use absolute path. the issue still happen

@NiuAr Did you tried to print the log?

sprintf(cmd, "cd /home/root/; tar -czvf %s-DClog-%d-Now.7z /home/root/dclogs 2> error.log", ModTcpIPA->DC1SN[0], nowtime);
system(cmd);

@NiuAr - how does tar function probable show fail relate to sometime i reboot the system, it work normally???????

Log the generated command. Maybe sometimes your variables contain not what you expect, leading to an invalid filename.

I print the cmd, it look correct, but tar result keep failed.
tar cmd: cd /home/root/;tar -czvf /home/root/O9C24500050WM-DClog-1734348097-Now.7z /home/root/dclogs > error.log
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
gzip: short write
tar: write error: Broken pipe
the error log, no information, please refer below as:
root@am335x-evm:~# cat error.log
home/root/dclogs
